# Convert unknown encoding into utf-8

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, utf-8, diacritics

I'm using a json service returning strings written in French containing accents. The things is I don't receive them correctly as the accents are replaced by symbols 'é' => '?'

I'm guessing the problem is the encoding but i tried to convert the string into  every single encoding into utf8

```
      var allTheEncoding = Encoding.GetEncodings();
      foreach (var encodingInfo in encoding)
      {
          var decoByte = encodingInfo.GetEncoding().GetBytes(str);
          var utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(encodingInfo.GetEncoding(), utf8, decoByte);
          str = utf8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
      }
```

And I still got the same probleme
Am I doing it right ? What should I do??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not even trying to encode the wrong thing once it had been converted. You can specify the encoding when it receives and converts only after receiving a byte array.

Comment: You're going to have to figure out what the encoding of the source data is. Perhaps you can figure it out empirically by poking at it here and there, but you should not try to write your application to figure out the source encoding on the fly. Either figure out the source encoding and require that the encoding never deviate, or require that your source indicate to you what encoding it is using. For example, in HTTP the character encoding is indicated in the Content-Type header, charset field. In an XML document, the character encoding is indicated in the XML Declaration.

Comment: Thanks for your answers but I went at source and they had an error at their end. Since then they repaired it and everything works

Answer (score 1):

You're shutting the stable door after the horse has bolted.

Don't work on `str`, work on the original stream that became `str`, since it was when `str` was created that the error crept in.